# Отображать изображения из базы данных sqlite в столбец в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

Я застрял в проблеме, которая отображает изображения в каждой строке в столбце фотографии из базы данных SQLite

Вот мой код и заранее спасибо:

```
void produits::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    login conn3;
    QSqlQueryModel * modal3=new QSqlQueryModel();

    conn3.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery* qry=new QSqlQuery(conn3.mydb);

    qry->prepare("select * from produits");

    qry->exec();
    modal3->setQuery(*qry);

    ui->tableView->setModel(modal3);
    conn3.connClose();

    qDebug() << (modal3->rowCount());
}
```

Comment: Покажите: ожидаемое поведение; поведение, которое есть сейчас.

Comment: @V-Mor что вы имеете в виду ?

Comment: Нужно реализовать свой [делегат](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html).

Comment: Может вот так будет понятнее: *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*

Comment: Вот из перечисленного у Вас не хватает нормального понятного описания желательного поведения и конкретной проблемы или ошибки.